# Run laserscanner in Android

Tags: ros, usb, laserscanner, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to driver my Laserscanner under Android system (a smartphone or a tab). I am using Hokoyo Laserscanner UTM-30LX.  Does anyone have experience?

How to supply the Laserscanner from smartphone or tab? Do I need an adapter to give the scanner appropriate Voltage?

Normally the USB in smartphone or tab has a mini USB. How can I use a Y cable to connect the Laserscanner and the smartphone or tab?

For your answer my heartfelt appreciation!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125851/run-laserscanner-in-android/) by [Yuliang Sun](https://answers.ros.org/users/10781/yuliang-sun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think this is going to work. You'll need 12V. Technically you can build a voltage converter that gives you 12V from USB voltage, but I think a smartphone USB will be way too less power for a UTM-30LX. It's definitely too much for USB specs. Do NOT use a Y cable!!!

In addition, you'll need a USB host port. My guess is most smartphones don't have that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0